# How to skip `for` loop index if an error occurs

Tags: matlab, for-loop, error-handling, skip, conditional-breakpoint

In Matlab, if an error occurs, how can I skip that certain `for` loop index and `continue` to the next index? Note that I do not know which `for` loop indices will cause the error to occur.

Error: **`Too many outputs requested.  Most likely cause is missing [] around left hand side that has a comma separated list expansion`**

Let's assume that an error occurs when `k = 5`.
How can I make the `for` loop skip index `k = 5` and `continue` to `k = 6`?

```
for k = 1:10
    do stuff
    if error occurs
       skip k that causes error
       go to next k
    end
end
```

Comment: Note that 'break' in Matlab will exit the whole loop. 'continue' will continue to the next iteration. It will save you pain along the road.

Comment: Oh yeah, I actually meant `continue`, thanks I'll edit my question.

Comment: what do you mean with "`if error occurs`"? Error handling is by its nature ad hoc and multiple error handling methods are often used in the same program. Different approaches are recommended depending on what you mean with "error occurs".

Comment: @patrik, I have edited the question

Comment: @Senyokbalgul Unfortunately this does not clarifies the post. What I was asking was _why_ you got this error and not for the specific error message. What is the reason to that the error can occur in the first place and **is this expected**. If it is, then you need to handle it for these cases. This can be done in different was depending on coding preferences and complexity. In case the error can occur in multiple places and is meant to be handled the same way, the try-catch may be good. Else, you can look for empty arrays/cells/structs to stop it before it occurs...

Comment: @patrik If it was an error that was important to correct, I would have done it. But in this case, it was not an important error to correct. I was trying to plot multiple graphs on a single axes. If `length(data{k})` is less than 2, there would be an error at that certain `k` index, while if `length(data{k})` was greater than 2, the graph can be plotted. I wanted to skip the data which was not plottable since a curve cannot be fitted to a single datapoint. Thus, it was not an important error to correct and I wanted to find a lazy way past this.

Comment: @Senyokbalgul So why not put that `if length(data{k}) > 2` around your `do stuff`?

Comment: @Senyokbalgul Error should always be corrected! Warnings should also always be corrected! At least to help future readers of your code, which can also be a future version of yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`try`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html)** for this purpose!

```
for k = 1:10
        %do stuff
        try
         % portion of the code where error can occur
        end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the very simple solution.

Comment: @Senyokbalgul Although this is the only way to do exactly what you want, this is not best way to handle the situation. Error catching is extremely expensive in terms of executation time, and more intended to catch unexpected errors. If you expect errors, solve them in the code. With the `try` you will not be able to find any other error anymore, because they are absorbed!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know which `k` is making error use:

```
for i=1:10
try
    %do stuff;
catch
    warning('some error');
end
```

If you know the `k`, a simple way can be this:

```
for k = 1:10
    if k==6
    else
        disp(k);
    end
end
```

If you already know which `k` is causing the error:

```
for k = [1:5 7:10]
        disp(k);
end
```

Comment: I've edited the question. I don't know which `k` will cause the error to occur actually.

Answer (score 0):

In case you require a vector of a specific length, else you would get an error there are two good ways this can be handled.

1) Use try-catch.

2) Do a pre range check, eg. `if (length(data)<2), continue;`

If you get the error only once you can choose either (1) or (2). Preferably choose a way that match the rest of the code. In case the error can occur in multiple places in the code and needs to be handled the same way in all of these, use (1). This will allow you to handle all the errors in the same place.

As far as I know there are a lot of different opinions in how to handle Exceptions (where I refer to MATLAB Errors with the more generic name "Exception"). A C-programmer would likely say that Exceptions should be used sparsely, while a Java programmer would use them more often. However there is no **goto** keyword in Java, and the C-programmer would probably handle the "Exception situation" by using **goto** in many places, even if it is considered bad practice to use the **goto** keyword too much. So as you see, there are many ways to do error handling. We can help with different alternatives, but in the end it will always be your choice (Sorry!).